# Segmentation Fault on simple Gearman code. PHP Cli

Tags: php, libc, gearman

This is very sad story. I'm trying to start using Gearman in my project. But can't to run simple test.

```
root@140141-10009:~# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS"
```

PHP

```
root@140141-10009:~# php -v
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 18:59:41)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Gearman

```
root@140141-10009:~# gearmand -V
gearmand 0.34 - https://bugs.launchpad.net/gearmand
```

PHP PECL Gearman 1.1.0, compliled from source without errors. All (2) tests passed. No other PHP extensions are enabled.

client.php:

```
<?php
$client = new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer('127.0.0.1');
$client->setTimeout(10000);
$client->addTask('taskplus2', 10);
$client->addTask('taskplus2', 15);
$client->runTasks();
```

Error:

```
root@140141-10009:~/gearman/proto# php client.php
Segmentation fault
```

dmesg:

```
[15066.824900] php[20520]: segfault at f ip 00007f128470ba40 sp 00007fffd9f1dd28 error 4 in libc-2.15.so[7f12845c1000+1b5000]
```

I already tried PHP 5.3, 5.4, Ububtu 10.04, 12.04, using gearman-ppa and not using. I also tried PECL Gearman 0.8.1, 0.8.3, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.1.0. Installing that all to clean-setup of Ubuntu. Googling of `libc6 gearman` was no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`GearmanClient::addTask()`](http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.addtask.php) accepts a string and not an integer as the second parameter.

Try:

```
$client->addTask('taskplus2', serialize(10));
```

Comment: Yes, that's right. Thank you.
And why it doesn't throw an exception instead of segfault...

Comment: And this is PHP ... how hard would it really be for the extension to convert a scalar type to a string for you? C'mon extension authors.

Comment: It is not hard to do it but it is fundamentally wrong: It is not only scalars that might be passed as argument but objects as well; I might want to use JSON encoded string, someone else might use XML string, you might prefer PHP serialized string. However, issuing warning or throwing exception in the case string is not passed as argument will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try update gearmand version to 1.1.2 from the oficial website.

Comment: Thanks. I tryied several versions of server and extension, but all of them was affected.